# Insert Code into Middle of Channel Entry Post

Tags: channel-entries, javascript, embeds, variable, snippets

I have a channel that stores ads (HTML ads I created and the Google Adsense Code block), and  displays either my html or Google's JS to allow a random ad on each page load. I want to insert that channel entry code from my Ad Channel in the middle of every post from my Article Channel – say after the 6th paragraph.

I could split the post entry field into two fields and do something like: " {postHalfOne}{adCodeSnippet}{postHalfTwo} ", but that doesn't allow for changing the breakpoint in the future.

Basic HTML can be inserted after a certain number of paragraphs via javascript, but it is my understanding that javascript can not be used to pass ExpressionEngine code. My test code works to insert HTML ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DesignBloke/9kkzyry5/)), just not with my exp:channel:entries code. Can I change my code to work with EE or is JS the wrong solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would to go with a [Blocks](https://eeblocks.com) or [Content Elements](http://www.krea.com/content-elements) approach, where your content is actually a list of content building blocks. Then you can have any combination: text-ad-text, text-ad-ad-text, text-ad-text-ad-text, text-somethingelse-text-ad-text, etc.

The value of that is that editors can just click on an "Ad" button, instead of needing to remember that the syntax is `{advertisement}` to include an advertisement. And you can have a little bit more flexibility (especially if you need multiple ads).

*Disclosure: I wrote Blocks.*

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options here.

One is to wrap your entry content in the [Allow EE Code plugin](https://github.com/EllisLab/Allow-Eecode), and then include your ad code via an embed wherever you ant it to appear in your entry, e.g.

```
{embed="_embeds/ad"}
```

The other option is to use something like [NSM Transplant](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-transplant), with which you can do something like this.

Include this as a "token" for your ad inside your content:

```
{advertisement}
```

Then in your template:

```
{exp:nsm_transplant:body}

  {exp:channel:entries channel="ads" limit="1" dynamic="no"}
    {exp:nsm_transplant:content id="advertisement"}
      {ad_code}
      {!-- Whatever you need to include here for your ad to render --}
    {/exp:nsm_transplant:content}
  {/exp:channel:entries}

  {exp:channel:entries channel="articles" limit="1"}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    {content}
    {!-- {advertisement} inside of {content} will be parsed and replaced with the content inside of {exp:nsm_transplant:content} above --}
  {exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:nsm_transplant:body}
```

Comment: Also consider Hop Inject (https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hop-inject) as an alternative to NSM Transplant, doing much the same job but at a third of the price.